# Grails - Can't add child record to parent

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Trying to follow the example shown [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) I am trying to create a record which links to a parent record.

In my case I have two classes: Sensor, and Readings. I can create Sensors without any issues, but no matter how I try to create readings I seem to fail :(

I've been spinning my wheels for long enough, I'm throwing in the towel and hoping someone can spot my silly mistake(s).

One more thing - I want to post the data using JSON. But through the debugging process I'm not even looking at the JSON values, I've hard coded them and it still doesn't work.

ReadingsController.groovy

```
package grailshelloworld

import grails.converters.JSON
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class ReadingsController {

    def scaffold=Readings

        def save = {

                def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
                def result = slurper.parseText(request.reader.text)

                def s = new Sensor (sensorid: "SID", sensorname: "name", sensordescription: "description")
                        .addToReadings(reading: "blah")
                        .save()

                render ([ok: false] as JSON)


    }
}
```

sensor.groovy

```
package grailshelloworld

class Sensor {

    String sensorid
    String sensorname
    String sensordescription

    static hasMany = [readings: Readings]

    static constraints = {
        sensorid blank:false, nullable: false 
        sensorname blank:false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

Readings.grooovy

```
package grailshelloworld
import java.util.Formatter.DateTime;
class Readings {
    String reading
    static belongsTo = [sensor: Sensor]
}
```

Current error: argument type mismatch...

```
<dt>Class</dt><dd>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</dd><dt>Message</dt><dd>argument type mismatch</dd></dl><h2>Around line 15 of <span class="filename">grails-app/controllers/grailshelloworld/ReadingsController.groovy</span></h2>
<pre class="snippet"><code class="line"><span class="lineNumber">12:</span>     def slurper = new JsonSlurper()</code><code class="line"><span class="lineNumber">13:</span>        def result = slurper.parseText(request.reader.text)</code><code class="line"><span class="lineNumber">14:</span></code><code class="line error"><span class="lineNumber">15:</span>     def s = new Sensor (sensorid: &quot;SID&quot;, sensorname: &quot;name&quot;, sensordescription: &quot;description&quot;)</code><code class="line"><span class="lineNumber">16:</span>           .addToReadings(reading: &quot;blah&quot;)</code><code class="line"><span class="lineNumber">17:</span>          .save()</code><code class="line"><span class="lineNumber">18:</span></code></pre><h2>Around line 195 of <span class="filename">PageFragmentCachingFilter.java</span></h2>
```

Comment: Doesn't `addToReadings` adds a child to a parent? And you call it for a `Sensor` which is a parent. Maybe you should create a `Readings` and add it to a `Sensor`?

Comment: Can you show us what your JSON looks like coming in?  Since the error is on your parseText call, it might be an issue with the JSON.

Comment: @nidu - The code isn't even getting that far before the error is thrown.  And grails allows that syntax as long as the Readings with reading: "blah" actually exists.

Comment: Here's the curl command, along with the JSON: curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{"sensorid": "28-JSON-ABC", "collectorname": "collector.attic.pisdr", "reading": 93.3, "id": 43}' http://localhost:8080/GrailsHelloWorld/readings/save; echo ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it by explicitly creating a new `Readings`?

```
def s = new Sensor (sensorid: "SID", sensorname: "name", sensordescription: "description")
                    .addToReadings(new Readings(reading: 'blah'))
                    .save()
```

The error is saying "around line 15" which is the start to the `def s = ...` statement.

I know the docs say it can be done the way you are attempting - but it's worth a try.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for saving more countless hours of banging my head!