# Grails - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm writing an application on Grails. I'm trying to add child database record to parent table using addTo-method. I follow [this](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) documentation about addTo-method. And for example, documentation says create parent-class:

```
class Author {    String name
    static hasMany = [fiction: Book, nonFiction: Book]
}
```

Follow this I created my parent-class:

```
class Cafee {

    String cafeeName = ""
    int totalReservationPlaces = 0
    double placeCost = 0
    String currencyType = ""
    boolean isReservationAvailable = false
    boolean reservationTimeLimit = false
    boolean reservationDateLimit = false
    int totalPlaces = 0
    long startTimeLimit = 0
    long endTimeLimit = 0
    Date startDateLimit = new Date()
    Date endDateLimit = new Date()  

    static constraints = {
        cafeeName blank: false, unique: true
    }

    String getCafeeName(){
        return cafeeName
    }

    static hasMany = [admin: Person]
}
```

Documentation says create child-class:

```
class Book {    String title
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

Follow this I've created my child-class:

```
class Person {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    String inn = ""
    boolean isAdminCafee = false
    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static belongsTo = [cafee:Cafee]

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        firstName blank: false
        lastName blank: false
        password blank: false
        email blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        PersonAuthority.findAllByPerson(this).collect { it.authority }
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }
}
```

And documentation says to add child record to parent I must do something this:

```
def fictBook = new Book(title: "IT")
def nonFictBook = new Book(title: "On Writing: A Memoir of the Craft")
def a = new Author(name: "Stephen King")
             .addToFiction(fictBook)
             .addToNonFiction(nonFictBook)
             .save()
```

Follow it in Bootstrap I've done this:

```
def user = Person.findOrSaveWhere(username: 'testerAndrewRes', password:'password', firstName:'Andrew', lastName:'Bobkov', email:'pragm@gmail.com', isAdminCafee: true,
             inn: '1234567890')
         println user
         if(!user.authorities.contains(adminRole))
         {
             PersonAuthority.create(user, adminRole, true)
         }
         def newCafe = new Cafee(cafeeName: "Tarelka").addToAdmin(user).save()
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person
Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: PS. println user prints: restorator.auth.Person : (unsaved). Why? Because findOrSaveWhere must be allways refer on saved instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886331/grails-cant-add-child-record-to-parent how about you test it by doing the addToAdmin and then new Person.. as a test.. With findOrSave you don't flush so wonder if there is some other logic causing your issue  I would do a simplistic test before enhancing to other methods not per doc

Comment: Solved, show: [Grails, GORM, relationship. Optional child records][1]


  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709158/grails-gorm-relationship-optional-child-records

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear I think.
Try adding:

```
user.save(flush:true)
```

before:

```
def newCafe = new Cafee(cafeeName: "Tarelka").addToAdmin(user).save()
```

Comment: rather than user.save flush:true try user.save flush false

Comment: I don't think this helps in a transactional setting withTransaction{ } or a transactional service method.