# Grails, GORM, relationship. Optional child records

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For example, I've parent class Cafee:

```
class Cafee {    
    String name
    static hasMany = [
         admin: Person
    ]
}
```

and a child class Person:

```
class Person {    
    String name
    static belongsTo = [cafee: Cafee]
}
```

I've done some records to Cafee using:

```
def user = new Person(name: "Andrew")
def a = new Cafee(name: "Tarelka")
             .addToAdmin(user)
             .save()
```

Adding child to parent works fine, but when I trying to create Person-instance separately, for example:

```
def visitor = new Person(username: 'testerUser', password:'password', firstName:'Иван', lastName:'Иванов', email:'ivanov@gmail.com', isAdminCafee: false)
         visitor.save(flush:true)
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person
Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: restorator.auth.Person
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Try making `cafee` optional in `Person` domain. `cafee nullable: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here that aren't entirely obvious. One is that this form of `belongsTo`

```
static belongsTo = [cafee: Cafee]
```

is bidirectional, as compared to

```
static belongsTo = [Cafee]
```

which is undirectional; in both variants a `Cafee` can access its associated `Person` instances via its `admin` collection, but using the second syntax there's no direct way for a `Person` to know which `Cafee` it's associated with.

Declaring a `hasMany` like you did creates a `Set` of `Person`s in the class, and its name is the key you used in the `hasMany` map, in this case `admin`; it's as if you had added

```
Set<Person> admin
```

but you shouldn't because it's redundant - an AST transform adds that property to the bytecode.

Similarly, when declaring

```
static belongsTo = [cafee: Cafee]
```

a field of type `Cafee` with the name `cafee` is added to the class. It's as if you added

```
Cafee cafee
```

but again, please don't manually add either, just be aware that they're there.

So the problem is that persistent properties are not-null by default unless you override with `nullable: true`, so if you printed out the errors for that `Person` instance you'd see at least one complaining that the non-nullable `cafee` property is null. This works with `addToAdmin` because that method does a lot. If instantiates the set to a new `Set` interface implementation (probably just a `HashSet`) if it's null (which should only ever occurr when the domain class instance is new; a persistent set will never be null, just empty or containing items), then adds the `Person` to the collection, and finally if the relationship is bidirectional, it sets the backreference on the `Person` to the owning `Cafee`.

So all you're missing is setting the `Cafee` manually, either as part of the map constructor

```
user = new Person(cafee: a, username: 'testerUser', ...)
```

or later in the workflow (but before validation or saving)

```
user = new Person(username: 'testerUser', ...)
...
user.cafee = a
...
user.save()
```

Comment: thanks, I've added to Cafee class constraints cafee nullable: true. All works.